# vector iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator, stdvector

I'm currently working on a graph library for C++ and now got stuck at a point where I get an assertion error in debug mode during runtime. I also had a look an some other question here on SO but none of the questions and answers lead me to a solution. After reading in some forums I have the impression that this error happens because iterators become invalid as soon as the vector content is changed. (for example when using `erase()`) But as you can see in my code, I'm not modifying the vector, just iterating.

The error is in the line I marked with `//ASSERTION`. The strange thing is that `neighbor_it` doesn't point to the first object in `(*vertex_it)->neighbors(`) but to `0xfeeefeee`. When debugging through the code I can clearly see that the neighbors-vector contains at least one item. Shouldn't `neighbor_it` point to the first object in this vector?

For further information: `m_vertices` is a vector of all vertices in a graph and `vertex::neighbors()` returns a vector of edges (which have a pointer to the neighbor/destination vertex). In this method I want to remove all edges pointing to a certain vertex. Returns true if an according edge has been found and removed, false if there is no edge pointing to `p_vertex`.

```
bool graph::remove_edges_pointing_to( vertex* p_vertex )
{
    bool res = false;

    std::vector<vertex*>::iterator vertex_it = m_vertices.begin();

    // iterate through all vertices
    while( vertex_it != m_vertices.end() )
    {
        // iterator on first element of neighbors of vertex
        std::vector<edge*>::iterator neighbor_it = (*vertex_it)->neighbors().begin();

        // iterate through all successors of each vertex
        while( neighbor_it != (*vertex_it)->neighbors().end() ) //ASSERTION
        {
            if( (*neighbor_it)->dest() == p_vertex )
            {
                if( (*vertex_it)->remove_edge( *neighbor_it ) )
                {
                    res = true;
                }
            }

            neighbor_it++;
        }

        vertex_it++;
    }

    return res;
}
```

**EDIT: (Solution)**

Alright, here is my new code which works properly. `remove_edge()` now returns an iterator to the next object in the vector it removed the edge from. In addition `neighbors()` now returns a *reference* to the according vector.

```
bool graph::remove_edges_pointing_to( vertex* p_vertex )
{
    bool res = false;

    std::vector<vertex*>::iterator vertex_it = m_vertices.begin();

    // iterate through all vertices
    while( vertex_it != m_vertices.end() )
    {
        // iterator on first element of neighbors of vertex
        std::vector<edge*>::iterator neighbor_it = (*vertex_it)->neighbors().begin();

        // iterate through all successors of each vertex
        while( neighbor_it != (*vertex_it)->neighbors().end() )
        {
            if( (*neighbor_it)->dest() == p_vertex )
            {
                neighbor_it = (*vertex_it)->remove_edge( *neighbor_it );
                res = true;
            }
            else
            {
                neighbor_it++;
            }
        }

        vertex_it++;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Thanks again for your answers! :)

Comment: what does remove_edge() do? Does it touch any data used in your loop?

Comment: How is `neighbors()` defined?

Comment: remove_edge will remove an edge (a neighbor relation) from the vertex vertex_it is pointing to. But when the assertion is fired I didn't even reach the line where remove_edge is called.

Comment: I wrote in the question what neighbors() is. It is a std::vector<edge*> containing the neighbor-relations of a vertex.

Comment: @Exa: Then the problem is probably caused even before this whole function is called, as I see nothing in here that would cause it.

Comment: Yep, it was a referencing problem as gwiazdorrr pointed out. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess, given limited context you provided, is that `neighbours()` returns copy of `std::vector<edge*>`, instead of reference, i.e. `std::vector<edge*>&`. So after `begin()` call temporary object is disposed, and obtained iterator points to rubbish.

Comment: Probably a beginner's mistake, but yes, that was it. I will look into referencing to avoid those mistakes in the future, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that `remove_edge` modifies the underlying container of `neighbor_it`, thereby invalidating it, but I cannot be certain without seeing more of your code.

If this is a case, a possible solution would be to return an iterator to the next element after the deleted one, as done for instance by `std::vector::erase`.

Comment: Yep, that's another problem. After the removal, the iterator becomes invalid. I have to figure out how to go on iterating after removing one edge. Thank you.